# Заменить специальные html - символы обычными

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Я получаю код из *html* (напр.: `a > b`) и хочу проверить его на правильность.

Проблема в том, что когда я получаю *innerHTML* у элемента, то, например, символ `>` превращается в `&gt`.

Я мог бы решить проблему простым перебором всех спец. символов *html* и заменой на обычные символы, но это было бы очень долгим решением.

Есть ли какой-либо метод *js*, который преобразует специальные *html*-символы в обычные? *Я не хочу изобретать колесо*.

Comment: Модет проще получать innerText? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Comment: @AlexeyTen innerText не возвращает переносы строки(если только <br>, что неудобно)

Comment: Ну ещё есть textContent

Comment: @AlexeyTen вы уверены, что textContent корректно отобразит?

Comment: Проверьте, это несложно

Comment: @AlexeyTen ладно, проверю в ближайшее время

Answer (score 1):

jQuery

Для пробы вставьте это, например:

```
$(&#8216;form&#8217;).submit(function() {
  var theString = $(&#8216;#string&#8217;).val();
  var varTitle = $(&#8216;<textarea></textarea>&#8216;).html(theString).text();
  $(&#8216;#output&#8217;).text(varTitle);
  return false;
});
```

```js
$('form').submit(function() {
  var theString = $('#string').val();
  var varTitle = $('<textarea />').html(theString).text();
  $('#output').text(varTitle);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="string">Ввведите сущности</label>
    <input type="text" name="string" id="string" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="decode" />
  </fieldset>
</form>

<div id="output"></div>
```

```
function unescape(some) {
    return some
         .replace(/&lt;/g, "<")
         .replace(/&gt;/g, ">") 
// и т.д.        
 }
```

Просто js

```
var decodeEntities = (function() {
  // this prevents any overhead from creating the object each time
  var element = document.createElement('div');

  function decodeHTMLEntities (str) {
    if(str && typeof str === 'string') {
      // strip script/html tags
      str = str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '');
      str = str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
      element.innerHTML = str;
      str = element.textContent;
      element.textContent = '';
    }

    return str;
  }

  return decodeHTMLEntities;
})();
```

Comment: Вы перебираете символы, а мне нужен какой-либо системный js метод, который сам всё это делает; *представьте сколько символов придется перебрать если делать расчет на то, что нужно перебрать все спец. символы*

Comment: Ну или уже готовый метод, включающий все спец. символы

Comment: Думаю, что это кто-то уже делал до меня

Comment: Не проще ли преобразовывать сразу, когда получаете innerHTML? В общем, далее тема понятна - немного доточите под себя по аналогии.

Comment: я и получаю innerHTML и тоже перебираю символы, но мне лень перебирать все спец. символы , которые есть в html (а в строке могут быть они все); при этом мне нужно оставить переносы строки, что и делает innerHTML ; я знаю, что можно сделать то, что я хочу с помощью свойства innerText, но в нем , чтобы поставить перенос строки, нужно ставить *<br>*, что не удобно для пользователя.

Comment: Извините, а обычным **js** (без jq) можете показать?